# Add new tags to Chosen Widget or Display All on Autocomplete Deluxe

Tags: taxonomy-terms, ajax

Trying to find a combination of the features provided by the [Autocomplete Deluxe](https://www.drupal.org/project/autocomplete_deluxe) widget and the [Chosen](https://www.drupal.org/project/chosen) module.

They're both great in their own right, but I either need Autocomplete Deluxe to display all options when you click the field (like it does in Chosen) or be able to add new terms to a Chosen field (like you can with Autocomplete Deluxe).

Chosen documentation implies it has this functionality, but I haven't been able to work out how to do it from a select list. And Autocomplete Deluxe, which should be pretty basic, I can't figure for the life of me how to trigger the drop-down to show.

Has anyone been able to do this successfully?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Autocomplete Deluxe, there looks like there's a bug in the code.

Update line 287 of the js file autocomplete_deluxe.js to include a question mark, as shown in the third last line of this block of code:

```
Drupal.autocomplete_deluxe.SingleWidget.prototype.setup = function() {
  var jqObject = this.jqObject;
  var parent = jqObject.parent();

  parent.mousedown(function() {
    if (parent.hasClass('autocomplete-deluxe-single-open')) {
      jqObject.autocomplete('close');
    } else {
      jqObject.autocomplete('search','?');
    }
  });
};
```

Also update the maximum results shown in line 30 of the module by changing to $limit = 0 (the default of 10 overrides whatever you have set for the field):

```
function autocomplete_deluxe_taxonomy_callback($field_name, $tags_typed = '', $limit = 0) {
```